# Java - SImple ESCP template not found

Tags: java

Currently i want to print a report in dot matrix printer using this: https://blog.jocki.me/simple-escp/

Here is my project directory:

[image: Preview]

This is my GUI Jframe to testing it

```
public class Index extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Index() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        initComponents();
        
        Template template = new JsonTemplate(Thread.currentThread().
           getContextClassLoader().getResource("com/app/tests/template.json").toURI()
        );
    }
  ... 
}
```

Let's running it by:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
       try {
          new Index().setVisible(true);
       } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
    });
    }
```

I got error:
How to access those template.json ?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.app.views.Index.<init>(Index.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also your files/resources should exists under tests/resources.

The folder structure should look like:

-src
-- test
--- resources
--- your-custom-folder
--- template.json

Then try:

```
AnyTestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("your-custom-folder/template.json")

or try the below: 

AnyTestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your-custom-folder/template.json")
```

If it is a class that is not a Test class, then your resources should be under src/main/resources/your-custom-folder/template.json

```
Then its Index.class.getClassLoader().getResource()
```

Comment: It's look confusing, the project is generated by netbeans

Comment: create resources folder under src/main   and under src/test,   then put your file there.